# Static Vector Multiply - No New Objects

Tags: java, vector, static

Is there a way to have a static method such that it returns a Vector object (with a simple integer x and y value as fields) which is a Vector multiplied by an int value argument. However, there are no new objects made, i.e, the object assigned to the return value is changed instead of there being a new Vector created?

The following code does not achieve this:

```
public class Vector{
  public int x,y;

  public Vector(int x,int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  //Important code starts

  public static Vector mult(Vector v,int a){
    return new Vector(v.x*a,v.y*a);
  }

  //Important code stops
}
```

This code is what I'm after but it's too messy:

```
public static Vector mult(Vector v1,Vector v2,int a){
  v1.x = v2.x*a;
  v1.y = v2.y*a;
}
```

Is there an alternative?

Comment: How is a two line method too messy?

Comment: Why not just create a method on `Vector` that modifies the x and y values by a scalar? It seems like you're trying to circumvent OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add:

```
public void multiply(Vector otherVector, int a){
  x = otherVector.x * a;
  y = otherVector.y * a;
}
```

to your Vector class.

Comment: You probably mean `public void`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
public void mult(double a) {
    x *= a;
    y *= a;
}
```